# Are there implications to reconnecting a ZMQ socket with the same identity?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I am connecting a DEALER socket to a ROUTER using:

```
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, 'id')
socket.connect('tcp://myhost:3456')
```

and frequently re-connecting is by calling:

```
socket.close()
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, 'id')
socket.connect('tcp://myhost:3456')
```

I'm using the same `id` each time and was wonder if there are any implications to doing this? I've also occasionally seen the following error in the console and not sure if it's related:

```
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/stream_engine.cpp:831)
```

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why you're closing and re-opening the socket so frequently?  Especially if, as in your code here, you're *immediately* re-opening the socket?  Typically there should be very little reason to do that.

Beyond that, there should be no ill effect from re-using the same ID so long as the previous socket to use it is no longer connected... According to [the documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-setsockopt#toc16), if the Router socket has not yet relinquished it's connection to the previous socket (which may or may not be an issue in practice), you determine how your Router socket will behave with the `ZMQ_ROUTER_HANDOVER` option.  It will either reject the new connection, or it will hand over the connection to the new socket... I assume the second one is what you're after.

I wouldn't think a rejected connection would result in the error you're seeing, though I suppose it's possible depending on what code follows what you've provided here.  If you think it's related, just make sure to check for a successful connection before you try to use that connection... I don't know if the pyzmq binding (or ZMQ itself) fails hard or if you have to test for it on a rejected connection.